# is it possible to list the commands pandoc or latexmk are running? or is it already telling me enough to fix the problem?

Tags: pdftex, glossaries, pandoc, latexmk

I'm still pretty new to LaTeX and I've got a fairly ridiculous process, but it's been working. I just don't know how to debug some problems when they come up.

The pandoc command I'm running is:

```
pandoc -f markdown --data-dir=./tex-junk -t latex --pdf-engine=latexmk --pdf-engine-opt=-outdir=./tex-junk \
   --resource-path=.:figures:scripts:non-roam-markdown:tex-stuff --number-sections --variable secnumdepth=3 \
   --toc --toc-depth=5 --filter pandoc-numbering --filter pandoc-crossref --filter pandoc-citeproc \
   --bibliography ./tex-stuff/ClinicalCodeSetManagement.bib --lua-filter scripts/pandoc-gls.lua \
   -M codeBlockCaptions=true -o ./tex-junk/paper.pdf ./non-roam-markdown/top.md \
   ./ready-for-pandoc/cscw-paper-intro.md ./ready-for-pandoc/cscw-related-work.md \
   ./ready-for-pandoc/cscw-methods.md ./ready-for-pandoc/cscw-results.md \
   ./ready-for-pandoc/cscw-discussion-findings.md ./non-roam-markdown/cscw-app-survey.md \
   ./non-roam-markdown/bottom.md
```

And the output is:

```latex
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of (pdf)latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 4 reference(s)
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'tex-junk/input.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
Error producing PDF.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
l.2314 \Glspl{cqm}
```

I thought if I could see what options `latexmk` is sending to `pdflatex`, I could fiddle with my glossary file and the tex file that `pandoc` generated and maybe figure out what's going on. I figured that would be something I could get from `--verbose` or some other option I could pass, but apparently not.

Answering the second question in the title would be more helpful than answering the first, but **if you'd like just to answer the first, you can skip reading everything below.** I'd also welcome critique/suggestions about my awful, kitchen-sink approach to document compilation.

The relevant part of input.log seems to be the **circled parts** in here:

```latex
Package longtable Warning: Column widths have changed
(longtable)                in table 2 on input line 2217.

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Package glossaries Warning: Empty glossary for \printnoidxglossary[type={part}]  |
| . Rerun may be required (or you may have forgotten to use commands like \gls) o  |
| n input line 2219.                                                               |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[28]
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
        -------------
l.2314 | \Glspl{cqm} |
        -------------
                   are standardized algorithms (each including multiple 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 25816 strings out of 480471
```

Line 2219 from `input.tex` that it doesn't like is this:

```latex
+\printnoidxglossary[type=part,sort=def]
```

The glossary is definitely not empty. The entry it's choking on is `cqm`, which is both an acronym and a glossary entry (which has been working fine for other stuff). Here are all the occurrences of it in the glossary file:

```latex
\newacronym{cqm}{CQM}{\gls{CQM}}

\newglossaryentry{CQM}
{name={clinical quality measure},
description={These are things that...}}
```

Many thanks for reading this far, if you did! And thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You should try to make an MWE in order for anybody to be able to help you. I am also pretty new here, but just from looking at source you are posting, seems to me that you are using `\label` as `\section` argument. I think that is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can try to do that. Do you recommend I just delete this question and start the MWE as a new question? I spent a long time on this one, but I can see that it's fairly impenetrable.... Also, I did find a workaround, but it took hours, so I realized that my real question is about how to improve my latex debugging process.

Comment: Why is this even adding hypertargets manually? Label will already make the cqm target

Comment: Sorry, I thought I deleted that. It wasn't the problem. And it was generated by the pandoc-gls lua filter. I'll delete that from the question now.

Comment: @Sigfried LaTeX debugging is not easy. I am struggling with it too. Given you are also using pandoc, in case of any errors you should try to inspect the intermediate tex file generated by pandoc. What was the workaround you have done?

Comment: One of my glossary markup things was messing up so I just spelled out the term. The other was a place where I had some latex in my markdown and then some latex-unfriendly markdown inside that bit of latex. I get stung by that one every so often and it usually takes forever to find those. I'm getting some cool stuff from latex, but it's been a drag. I think I can do pandoc-citeproc without latex, but I'm not sure about glossaries, or what other latex dependencies I have. When I have time, I may try to switch to some other output format from pandoc.